# How to remove/override the CSS of element property that is marked as !important

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I need a help from your side,
Actually, I am working on WordPress website and created a post recently. The post is working fine. There are 4 fields basically to fill the form for the comment reply; Name, Email, Website, and Comments. First 3 fields are text fields and the last one is the textarea field.

When I am going to fill the form for a reply then name, email, website fields are filled without any CSS disturbance. But when I click on the comments box the height of the box is reduced. This is the main problem that arises. I don't know why this happens only in posts comments fields section.

```css
/* When the posts page is refreshed and I inspected and found this CSS */

.comment-form textarea {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border: 0;
    height: 106px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: none;
}

/* When I click on textarea field then CSS changes and what I found */

element {
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important;
    z-index: auto;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
'comment_field' =>  '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">
            </label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Comment', 'spa-and-salon' ) . '" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true">' .
            '</textarea></p>',
```

This is some WordPress code that I have found:

```
$args = array(
          'id_form'           => 'commentform',
          'class_form'      => 'comment-form',
          'id_submit'         => 'submit',
          'class_submit'      => 'submit',
          'name_submit'       => 'submit',
          'title_reply'       => esc_attr__( 'Leave a Reply', 'spa-and-salon' ),
          'title_reply_to'    => esc_attr__( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'spa-and-salon' ),
          'cancel_reply_link' => esc_attr__( 'Cancel Reply', 'spa-and-salon' ),
          'label_submit'      => esc_attr__( 'POST COMMENT', 'spa-and-salon' ),
          'format'            => 'xhtml',
```

Please help me for that the height of textarea remains same before click and after the click to fill any reply over there. How we can override the autogenerated CSS in WordPress. Help?

**Note: I think the backgorund (background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important;) of the element property will disturb the css for the textarea**

Comment: You should use jquery to overrid property with important this.style.setProperty( 'border', 'none', 'important' );

Comment: If your site is live, can you provide link to the form?

Comment: http://saloon.ekvitech.com/spa-and-massage/  here is the URL you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try  this.

```
$(".comment-form textarea").css("cssText", "background: #f7f7f7 !important; height: 106px;");
```

Comment: not works dear I have tried this. Again the Comment box height get reduced after click on it.

Comment: please will you check is this the right way to perform. I add this in header.php file and this is my jquery script,
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("textarea").focus(function(){
  jQuery(".comment-form textarea").css("cssText", "background: #f7f7f7 !important; height: 106px;");
  //this.style.setProperty( 'border', 'none', 'important' ); 
    //alert("The textarea was clicked.");
}); 
});

Comment: Give like this. I have checked. It's working.
`jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  jQuery("textarea").focus(function(){ 
    jQuery(".comment-form textarea").css("cssText", "background: #f7f7f7 !important; height: 106px;"); 
    alert("The textarea was clicked.");
  });
});
`

Comment: Not working. Actually, I am working on local first then commit my changes to live.

Comment: Hi @ankita patel, will you tell me where I can add this code and in which file. I am using WordPress. So the jquery lib will conflict with others.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("textarea").focus(function(){ jQuery(".comment-form textarea").css("cssText", "background: #f7f7f7 !important; height: 106px;"); alert("The textarea was clicked."); }); });
</script>

will you help how the code I will use the form here and where actually I will be applying?

Comment: you have checked that it's conflict..? because jQuery add in header.php file.

Comment: and some other code will affect. I am using this code in header.php. Please help.

Comment: use like this to avoid conflict jQuery:
`var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
jQ(document).ready(function(){ 
 jQ("textarea").focus(function(){
 jQ(".comment-form textarea").css("cssText", "background: #f7f7f7 !important; height: 106px;"); 
 alert("The textarea was clicked."); 
 });
});`

Comment: did you check your script code is executed and comment box reduced its height. And if again click then it will normal and back to its original size but the comment heading is run away from field. What is this happening here, please help?

Comment: ok then you can also give normal height without focus. because by default you have given `height:50% !important` so remove it.

Comment: I have removed the height and the above script is working but the placeholder is hides and text color is transparent, what to do for this.

Comment: When this thing is happened focus or normal...?

Comment: Yes, Because currently, I am working on local, If changes work perfectly then I will commit them to live website.

Comment: Please help what to do, I don't know how to work with scripts and how to use jquery libs. Because if I include this <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> then css works but it will create problems in the rest of site. If I don't include then css not works. What is that.

Comment: Then how can I identify your problem..?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem,

```
#comment:active{
background:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override CSS properties of `!important` with `!important` but the new code need to be placed below the original one.

Your current code:

```
element {
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important;
    z-index: auto;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
}
```

The background can be overridden as, considering the following code is placed below the original/above code in the CSS file.

```
element {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Now, you have an issue where the comment message box field's height is decreased when clicked, try the following code for that.
**Code Updated**

```
.comment-form textarea {
    min-height: 106px;
    background: none !important;
}

.comment-form textarea:active {
    min-height: 106px;
    height: 106px;
}
```

If I may have guessed it right, `element` is added by browser so just ditch that and use the above updated CSS only.

You can add this CSS using the plugin [Simple Custom CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/).

Comment: Hi @Junaid, the element property is auto-generated by wordpress coding, how the posts know that this element is set for them, not for all other web pages. How we wrote this element {
    background: none !important;
} in the stylesheet, I think it will affect all other web pages elements too.

Comment: Should I use this one only in custom css,

.comment-form textarea {
    min-height: 106px;
    background: none !important;
}

.comment-form textarea:active {
    min-height: 106px;
    height: 106px;
}

Comment: Exactly. Make sure you clear your cache. If it doesn't work, open your browser dev tools and share screenshot of which CSS properties are being applied to the `text-area` element

Comment: what are browser dev tools,

Comment: What can i do now please help